# Evaluation of Irrational equations involving $2$ square root

Tags: indefinite-integrals

> Finding value of $\displaystyle \int \sqrt{x+\sqrt{kx-x^2}}dx$

My Try: Let $\displaystyle I = \sqrt{x+\sqrt{kx-x^2}}$. Substitute $kx-x^2=t^2$

Then $(k-2x)dx = dt$

$\Rightarrow \displaystyle I = \int \sqrt{x+t}\; \times \frac{1}{k-2x}dt$

Now $\displaystyle x^2-kx+t^2=0\Rightarrow x=\frac{k\pm \sqrt{k^2-4t^2}}{2}$

$\displaystyle \Rightarrow I = \pm \int \sqrt{\frac{k\pm \sqrt{k^2-4t^2}}{2}+t}\times \frac{1}{\sqrt{k^2-4t^2}}dt$

Could some help me how to solve it

please help me ,  Thanks

Comment: Use $$x-\dfrac{k}{2}=\dfrac{k}{2}\sin\theta$$

Comment: It seems that it would end to an Elliptic integral!

Comment: A few steps: With Nosrati's hint $x=\dfrac{k}{2}+\dfrac{k}{2}\sin\theta$:

$$
I = \int \sqrt{x+\sqrt{kx-x^2}}dx = \\
\left[\dfrac{k}{2}\right]^{3/2}  \int \sqrt{1+\sin\theta +\cos\theta} \; \cos\theta \; d\theta \\
= \left[\dfrac{k}{2}\right]^{3/2}  \int \sqrt{\sqrt{2} \sin(\theta + \pi/4) + 1}  \; \cos\theta \; d\theta \\
$$
.....

Comment: ...   Since $$\cos\theta  = \cos(\theta + \pi/4 - \pi/4) = \cos(\theta + \pi/4) \cos(\pi/4) -\sin(\theta + \pi/4) \sin(\pi/4)  \\= \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\cos(\theta + \pi/4) - \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\sin(\theta + \pi/4) $$  
set $\alpha = \theta + \pi/4$ and obtain 

$$
I 
 = \left[\dfrac{k}{2}\right]^{3/2}  \int \sqrt{\sqrt{2} \sin(\alpha) + 1}  \; (\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\cos(\alpha) - \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\sin(\alpha) ) \; d\alpha\\
$$ The first one is easy, the second one becomes elliptic